# How do I add "SELECT OPTIONS" on a simple product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to display 3 random products from my WooCommerce shop on my landing page, and I managed to do that.

The problem is, I want every randomly displayed product to have a "SELECT OPTIONS" button. It seems like all simple products have an "ADD TO CART" button.

Is there a way to have a "SELECT OPTIONS" button on a simple product which redirects to the single product page (i.e., as in the case of a variable product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` for this. You can put the following code inside of the functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_button($button,$product) {
    // Do not change the button for variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) return $button;

    $buttontext = __( "SELECT OPTIONS", "woocommerce" ); // your button text

    // replace the button to be a link to the product detail page
    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $buttontext . '</a>';
}
```

With this code, you check if it is a variable product. If it is, just return the button. If it is not (so it is a simple product), replace the button with a link to the product detail page.